# Requesting values of key from Postman form-data

Tags: python, validation, flask, postman, backend

I'm trying to write if statement validation code for my Flask API and I want to check if values of key are int or not but it seems like values stored in Postman form-data are string type. Is there any way that values can be stored in their original type?

```
 Here is my code: 


 if type(request.form['user_id']) is not int and (request.form['passport_url']) is not str:
    
        abort(make_response(jsonify(Error="UserId or PassportUrl type is not valid", Code="500"), 500))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`isNumeric`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.isnumeric) function to check if all characters in `user_id` are numeric characters.

```py
if not request.form['user_id'].isNumeric() and (request.form['passport_url']) is not str:
    ...
```

Then you can parse the `user_id` to int using [`int`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#int) function.

```py
user_id = int(request.form['user_id'])

# use user_id as int
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I ended up with this   if request.form['user_id'].isnumeric() != True and (request.form['passport_url']) is not str: